# Nested for loop array random numbers

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, visual-c++, random

So what i am trying to do is to print out 7 random numbers and the loop should not print out duplicates.
When i am trying to debug it seems that i don't get in to my nested loop where my if statement is.

i also get a memory value printed out and the random numbers is duplicated.

I believe there is something wrong in my 2nd nested for loop  but i cant figure out what, would appreciate some help if someone can see the issue and explain to me what's happening with my nested 2nd loop, step by step.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 35

int main()
{
int number[SIZE];

srand(time(NULL));

for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
{
    number[i] = rand() % 35 + 1;
    for (int j = 0; j > i; j++)
    {
        if (number[i] == number[i])
        printf("%d\n", number[i]);
        i--;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", number[i]);
}
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it "doesn't get into my nested loop", that doesn't happen for no reason.  You should use the debugger to identify the reason why (inspect variables, etc.)

Comment: When would `if (number[i] == number[i])` ever be false?

Comment: Aside: `rand() % 35` ==> `rand() % SIZE`. Also what is magic number `7` for, when the array has length `SIZE` (35)? You seem to have confused the number of values, with their range.

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j > i; j++)` if `i` starts at `1` and `j` starts at `0` when will `j` ever be greater than `i`?

Comment: Indeed, thx, yes i am a bit confused with the numbers and their range, just want to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

For starters this loop

```
for (int j = 0; j > i; j++)
```

will be executed never because `j` is initialized such a way that it is always less than `i`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE    35

int main(void) 
{
    int number[SIZE];
    int n = 7;

    int i = 0;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    while ( i < n )
    {
        int value = rand() % SIZE + 1;

        int j = 0;
        while ( j < i && number[j] != value ) j++;

        if ( j == i ) number[i++] = value;
    }

    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", number[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might be

```
10 21 16 17 26 25 34
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have confused the number of values required, with their range.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 35
#define VALS 7

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    int had[SIZE] = { 0 };          // status array
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < VALS; i++) {
        do {
            j = rand() % SIZE;      // range 0..34
        } while(had[j] != 0);       // until new value had
        had[j] = 1;                 // set status
        printf("%d ", j + 1);       // range 1..35
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
33 25 17 28 2 27 10
```